# How to print all the prime numbers from 1 to 1000?

Tags: c, primes

I'm trying to write a program that goes through all the numbers from one to a thousand, but it does not work. Here is what I wrote so far, I could not find the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, mona = 0;
    bool prime = true;
    //for each number between 1-1000
    //i go over the numbers between two(It's ok if the number is divisible by 1,Every number is divisible 
 by 1) and this number (not including the number itself)
    //if the number is divisible by any number, it is not a prime number
    for(i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) 
                prime = false;
            if (prime)
                {
                printf("prime number: %d\n", i);
                mona++;
                }
            }
        }
    printf("number of prime numbers: %d", mona);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output i got:

```
prime number: 3
number of prime numbers: 1
```

I also see that I did not consider the number two.

Comment: Well, you're never setting `prime` back to true. Once it's false, it never goes back.

Comment: thanks, it still doesn't work, but that is one of the problems.now it just prints every number between 1-1000 and also it print each number multi[ple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a solution:

```
int i, int j;
int count=0;
int mona=0;
  for(i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j != 0) 
            count++;
    }
  if (count==i-2){
            printf("prime number: %d\n", i);
            mona++;
            }
 count=0
 }
```

With "count", you count the number of division with rest different from 0. If all the division satisfy the previous condition, the number is prime. The number of division computed by second cycle for a specific number is equal to i-2.

Comment: This code has several errors that prevent compilation. Once correct, the resulting code is hugely wasteful. There is no reason to continue testing once a factor is found.

Comment: Hi, I have not compiled the code, then when I see my answer I see the error. Anyway, I want to give to boy that has asked this question, the idea with which he can solve his problem. From the question, I understood that boy hasn't started programming for a long time, so there's no reason to complicate the code by optimizing it.

Comment: I started programming recently, I'm 14. Your answer helped me thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
for(i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
    prime = true;
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

Clearly if the flag is tested every time around the outer loop it needs to be initialized every time around the outer loop.